# Stripe subscriptions - When testing clocks, an automatic invoice with status paid is getting created on advancing time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I use the following firebase extension for stripe payment integration in my react app - https://extensions.dev/extensions/stripe/firestore-stripe-payments. (I cannot share the code from the app, but can try snippets if need be). The steps to set it up are described here - https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/sample-stripe-payment-demo/extensions/instances/firestore-stripe-payments?tab=usage

I have a product to which I want to setup monthly recurring payments. In order to test out that, when the next billing cycle starts, there should be an invoice generated which will lead to the user / customer having to pay again, I simulate subscriptions using the steps described here - https://docs.stripe.com/billing/testing/test-clocks/simulate-subscriptions/ . I advance the clock by one or two months and check in my firestore database if there is an invoice generated.  (with firbase stripe extension, things like customers, subscriptions, invoices are stored as collections in a firestore database).

What I expect when advancing time - in the `customers/subscriptions` collection for the particular customer for whom I advanced time, the subscription status should not be 'active' since the user has now 'not paid' for this billing cycle.

Instead I see subscription status as 'active' and in another collection , an invoice for that billing cycle `customers/subscriptions/[subscriptionid]/invoices/[invoiceid]` with status 'paid'.

Question - How do I properly test out my subscriptions payment stripe integration when using this particular extension?

My main reference is this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xi3F2Zv91UE and the code link in the description

Comment: Why do you think this Invoice should not be paid? From your wording, it seems you expect the Customer to have to pay manually for the new Invoices, which would only be the case for Subscription with `collection_method=send_invoice`, however the Youtube tutorial you shared shows Subscriptions created with Checkout sessions, which would be set with `collection_method=charge_automatically`. As such, the customer would be automatically charged for their upcoming period when the Invoice is created, and the Invoice should be paid so long as that payment method stays valid.

Comment: Thank you for point this out. So, to test that out, if I remove the payment method, will the generated invoice status be something else and will the subscription status show inactive?

Comment: You can do that yes. Technically, I believe the behavior for Invoices charging invalid payment methods VS that of Invoices missing the payment method isn't exactly the same, so if your objective is to test what would happen, then the most accurate way would be to replace your Customer's payment method with this one: `4000000000000341` https://docs.stripe.com/testing#declined-payments

Comment: In both scenarios the Subscription should not be `active`, but if I recall correctly, the Invoice won't generate any payment intent / charge if the payment method is missing, while it will if there is one. So if you have an invalid payment method, you'd have an inactive Subscription, unpaid Invoice, as well as a Payment Intent + Charge which are failed. With no payment method, you'd only have the Subscription and Invoice objects.

Comment: Btw just nitpicking something I said: "the customer would be automatically charged for their upcoming period when the Invoice is created". This is inaccurate, the customer gets charged when the Invoice is *finalized*, which is an hour after it is created for recurring Invoices